# Python Using Fileinput to Replace Words

Tags: python, linux, macos, fileinputstream

I am using Python 2.7 with MAC OS X and wrote a program to replace a word in a file with another word. Any time that word shows up in that file I want it replaced with another word that the user specifies. It seems to be working but it seems to be outputting a couple extra lines on the bottom that are copied from the file. Does anyone know why it is doing this?

Original file:

```
TCPServeraddress      april.com
NODename              hostname
COMMmethod            TCPip
NFSTIMEout            0
TCPBuffsize           32
TXNB                  25600
TCPWINDOWSIZE         64
TCPNODELAY            YES
LARGECOMMBUFFERS      YES
MANAGEDServices     Schedule
SCHEDMODe             prompted
PASSWORDAccess        generate
ERRORLOGRetention     2 d
ERRORLOGName          /ngs/hostname/logs/dsmerror.log
SCHEDLOGRetention     2 d
SCHEDLOGName          /ngs/hostname/logs/dsmsched.log
```

After running my script, the user will input "test" as hostname:

```
import fileinput


textToSearch = "hostname" 
print ("Please type in the TSM Hostname:")
textToReplace = raw_input( "Hostname/Nodename: " )

print ("***Updating dsm.sys file****")
fileToSearch  = "/Users/bob/Desktop/FinalizedPythonScripts/helloworld"

tempFile = open( fileToSearch, 'r+' )

for line in fileinput.input( fileToSearch ):
    tempFile.write( line.replace( textToSearch, textToReplace ) )
tempFile.close()
```

I get the modified file correctly but has the extra "smsched.log" as the last line which does not exist in the original file, I have repeated this process and it happens everytime:

```
TCPServeraddress      april.com
NODename              test
COMMmethod            TCPip
NFSTIMEout            0
TCPBuffsize           32
TXNB                  25600
TCPWINDOWSIZE         64
TCPNODELAY            YES
LARGECOMMBUFFERS      YES
MANAGEDServices     Schedule
SCHEDMODe             prompted
PASSWORDAccess        generate
ERRORLOGRetention     2 d
ERRORLOGName          /ngs/test/logs/dsmerror.log
SCHEDLOGRetention     2 d
SCHEDLOGName          /ngs/test/logs/dsmsched.log
smsched.log
```

Comment: Probably caused by modifying a file while iterating over it with `fileinput.input`. Maybe better to load the file into memory, modify it, and then write the output back in a single go. Especially if you're not using `fileinput` for anything in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `fileinput.input(filePath, inplace=True)` method instead of the `open(..) method`

Here's the script:

```
import fileinput

textToSearch = "hostname" 
print ("Please type in the TSM Hostname:")
textToReplace = raw_input( "Hostname/Nodename: " )
print ("***Updating dsm.sys file****")
fileToSearch  = "/Users/bob/Desktop/FinalizedPythonScripts/helloworld"
for line in fileinput.input(fileToSearch, inplace=True):
    print line.replace(textToSearch, textToReplace),
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after thinking about this for a long time, here is my answer:

<strike>change the open type from "r+" to "w" (or maybe "w+", haven't tried)</strike>

**Edit 2:** These don't seem to work. Try something like copying the contents of the file before re-writing it, then rewrite the file from scratch while reading out and formatting the copied contents.

Ok, let me elaborate:
I didn't go too deep into how "r+" mode works, but since it is supposed to allow *read and write*, I guess what happens is, when writing to your file, it replaces existing chars from the beginning on. for every newly written char, one is replaced (like replace mode in a text editor).

Now, when you write to your file `line.replace(textToSearch,textToReplace)`, it does the following with a valid line:

old line:

```
ERRORLOGName          /ngs/hostname/logs/dsmerror.log\n
```

new line:

```
ERRORLOGName          /ngs/test/logs/dsmerror.log\nlog\n
```

note how the last 4 characters are preserved, because hostname is 8 chars long, but test is 4 chars long.

this isn't obvious, since you copy `"\n"` at the end of each line, and respectively replace it as well. but at the end, you do 3 replaces (in this file's case), so you are left with the last 12 character: `"\nsmsched.log"`

Comment: I tried your suggestion but that ends up deleting all contents in the file "helloworld" after running the script

Comment: Sorry, I haven't tried it out. See my edit for elaboration. You might just find another way around it yourself. Try copying the file contents somewhere before opening for write, or try "w+" mode. The reason it deletes the content is because `for line in fileinput.input( fileToSearch ):` is executed *after* you open the file in write mode, which deletes everything.

Comment: I believe you are right about what is happening. I tried both "w" and "w+" but that just deletes the entire content of the file

Comment: If you try a longer replacement than "test" (more than 8 chars long), there are two things that could happen: either the new lines that are overwritten will be read by `fileinput` wrongly, thus resulting in even more corrupted output, or `fileinput` opens and reads the file beforehand - in this case, the error wouldn't even be apparent. What you could do in the latter case (for replacement strings shorter than "hostname") is count how often you do a replacement and then delete the last `rep_count*(len(textToSearch)-len(textToReplace))` if this happens to be a positive number.